# Interior and closure of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

We have $\mathbb{R}$ with euclidian topology. I would like to compute the interior and the closure of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ but I do not see it.

Answer (score 1):

The interior is empty, because for every rational in $[0,1]$, there exists an irrational arbitrary close to it.

The closure is $[0,1]$ because for every real number $x$ in $[0,1]$, there exists arbitrary close rationals to $x$, so you can find a sequence of rational which converges to $x$.

It all comes from the density of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Only the second point comes from the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$. The first comes from the density of the irrationals.

Comment: Of course, it all related anyway. But thanks for the remark, I edited.